# Angularjs + phonegap logout on history back

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I've created a mobile phonegap application using angularjs 1.1.5

On application run, a login form is displayed. After successful logging in, 
the user is redirected to a new '**/accounts/profile**' url (**ProfileCtrl** controller).

On every page (beside the login form located at '**/accounts/login**'), there is a back button
located on the top left of the screen.

The entire application is tied to "**AppCtrl**" controller (as well as topbar with the back button mentioned). The rest of the app is tied to a **ng-view** directive with separate controller for each.

The back button is  a function defined in an AppCtrl controller by simply returning `window.history.back()`

I need to disable the `window.history.back()` on the profile page (the one displayed after successful logging), located at "**/accounts/profile**" binded to **ProfileCtrl** controller.
Instead use user should be logged out. (I am omiting logout confirmation here.. for simplicity). The same should apply to hitting a back button of the phone.

At the moment, I am changing the `goBack()` function from the child scope with `$scope.$parent.goBack() = logout()` in **ProfileCtrl**.. but I have no idea, how would I bind it to physical back button.

Answer (score 0):

To bind to physical back button, you can use:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", $scope.goBack, false);
```

To do this, you need to use a combination Angular $window and $location service in your controller.  I would suggest against overriding your $parent scope function because your might get into weird behavior on another page.  Also, know that you are not allow to exit or suspend your app on iOS device.  See some sample codes below:

```
var AppCtrl = ['$scope', '$window', '$location', '$timeout', '$notification', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $window, $location, $timeout, $notification, $rootScope) {
'use strict';

// Somewhere inside AppCtrl
$scope.checkExit = function () {

    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14422908/iphone-does-not-recognize-phonegaps-navigator-app
    // fack!!!
    if ($location.path() == '/home' && !$scope.isIOS) {
        $notification.confirm("Exit application?", function(result) {
            if ($window.isPhoneGap && result == 1) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('appExit');  // ga tracking
                navigator.app.exitApp();
            }
        });
        return true;
    }

    return false;
};

$scope.goBack = function (evt) {
    if (evt != null) {
        if (evt.preventDefault) {
            evt.preventDefault();
        }
    }

    if (!$scope.checkExit()) {
        $window.history.back();
    }
};

document.addEventListener("backbutton", $scope.goBack, false);

}]; // End AppCtrl 

// in some other file, I have $notification friendly factory
app.factory('$notification', ['$rootScope', '$window', function ($rootScope, $window) {
  return {
     alert: function(message) {
         if (!$window.isPhoneGap) {
             $window.alert(message);
             return;
         }

         navigator.notification.alert(message, null, '', 'OK');
     },
     confirm: function (message, callbackFn, title, buttonLabels) {
         if (buttonLabels == null) {
             buttonLabels = 'OK,Cancel';
         }

         if (!$window.isPhoneGap) {
             callbackFn($window.confirm(message) ? 1 : 2);
             return;
         }

         navigator.notification.confirm(
                 message,       // message
                 callbackFn,    // callback to invoke with index of button pressed
                 title,         // title
                 buttonLabels.split(',')   // buttonLabels
             );
     },
     prompt: function (message, callbackFn, title, defaultText, buttonLabels) {
         if (buttonLabels == null) {
             buttonLabels = 'OK,Cancel';
         }
         if (defaultText == null) {
             defaultText = '';
         }

         if (!$window.isPhoneGap) {
             var answer = $window.prompt(message, defaultText);
             callbackFn({
                 buttonIndex: (answer ? 1 : 2),
                 input1: answer
             });
             return;
         }

         navigator.notification.prompt(
            message,        // message
            callbackFn,     // callback to invoke
            title,          // title
            buttonLabels.split(','),
            defaultText
        );
     }
  };
}]);
```

I set window.isPhoneGap early ondeviceready in this code example:  [navigator.connection.type not working even if device is ready *or* device is never ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17750667/navigator-connection-type-not-working-even-if-device-is-ready-or-device-is-nev/17754340#17754340)