# is there a difference between alert() vs notification.alert() using phonegap in xcode?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xcode, cordova

I'm trying to figure out how to fix the titles on my messages that pop up in my iOS app I am attempting to work on seeing as the messages tend to pop up with a long path of where the file is, then the message which is to a point counter productive for the needs of the popup. That said. I started searching for how to fix it and I came up with the `notification.alert()`. I am assuming that the standard `alert()` I am using is binded to that with the way cordova/phonegap works. But does this mean I should instead of `alert('message')` use `notification.alert()` if so. Then how can I fix the one that is auto generated by the app when I am looking for geolocation information?

As requested "What am I using for geolocation"

```
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
if(navigator.geolocation)
{
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
}
```

Which is what I do in my web based apps. I know this may not be the ideal solution for phonegap/cordova specifically. So I am searching for the right answer to this as well. But mostly the alerts. I am currently porting over an existing web based app to a phonegap version for iOS so the original question is should I remain using `alert()` where I do in my web based version or should I convert those as well to `notification.alert()` or does it really make that big a difference.

Comment: What do you mean with "auto generated by the app"? :)
It's recommended to use `notification.alert()`, since you can define a title and so on. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#notification.alert :)

Comment: Auto Generated.. as in when you attempt to get someones locaiton be it in a browser, or otherwise.. an alert is generated making a request for its authorization. I have no control over this that I am aware outright, but when ever I use apps on my phone, I dont see `/some/path/this/that/other/something/file.ext is requesting..` usually I see the apps name..

Answer (score 1):

Like Noogen already mentioned, you should use `notification.alert` if you want it to look native and you want to customize the title etc.

For iOS 6 and above, to change the alert asking for permission to use current location, you can set the value for key `NSLocationUsageDescription` (or Privacy - Location Usage Description) in your app's `Info.plist`. The title of the alert will still be *"YourAppBundleName" Would Like to Use Your Current Location*. The value of the NSLocationUsageDescription will be shown as an explanation below the title.

There are similar properties for other permission dialogs as described in Apple's [Information Property List Key Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html).

Answer (score 0):

What Google geolocation code are you using that is doing the alert?  API should not be doing any alert.  The alert and notification.alert are two different functions.

Default alert webview/browser display the page URL in the title.  Phonegap people did a great thing by providing the additional notification (alert, prompt, and confirm) API.  This is a feature/benefit of PhoneGap.  It is also required if you don't want to be rejected by Apple with app must be native look and feel clause.  Just change all your alert to notification.alert.

You can also hack/override default alert with window.alert = notification.alert, but I do not recommend this.

Alternatively, you can do something like my AngularJS phonegap $notification friendly factory shown in my response here:  [Angularjs + phonegap logout on history back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18080810/angularjs-phonegap-logout-on-history-back)

Comment: Ill add the spot I run at initialization of my app, that looks for the geo information.